# nginx reverse proxy issue with www-authenticate

Tags: nginx, centos7, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty, www-authenticate

I want to route the incoming http requests to port 8081 locally using nginx reverse proxy, but application running on 8081 needs www-authenticate header authorization and postman gives me status 401 "Authentication failure" (image 1). But when i do reverse proxy with Apache httpd i get the results successfully.

failing for www-authenticate
[image: Postman results nginx www-authentication]

Here its working for another request which uses basic authentications 
[image: Postman results nginx basic type authentication]

here is my nginx.conf

```
               location /webfolder/ {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
                    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

Please help me on this issue as im not familiar with nginx, nginx version 1.16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because i have "underscores in header" 
ex 
    CLIENT_SECRET_KEY

To resolve that, you need to add `underscores_in_headers on;` in your nginx.conf
problem solved.